# Merlin R package - Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:30: unexpected symbol

Tags: r

I'm running into an issue with an error code when using the merlin package and I can't figure out what the issue is. I know others have gotten this error message but I still don't know exactly what it means. Here is an example dataframe that has a similar structure as my real data:

```
dat = as.data.frame(list(fish = as.factor(c(rep("a",6),rep("b",6),rep("c",6),rep("d",6))),
                         value = as.numeric(c(1,3,7,7,6,7,2,4,8,7,7,6,5,8,10,11,12,10,3,7,9,9,8,9)),
                         time = as.numeric(rep(1:6,4)),
                         location = as.factor(c(rep("0",6),rep("1",6)))))
                    
dat
str(dat)


library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=time, y=value, group=fish, col=fish)) +
  geom_line()
```

Here, there were 4 fish in the experiment (a-d), and at each point in time (6 time points), a value was measured for each fish. location is a dummy variable that tells where the fish came from. Here, fishes "a" and "b" came from location "0" while fishes "c" and "d" came from location "1".

My goal is to examine how value changes over time and whether location is a significant factor (also if there is a significant time x location interaction). I initially fit a restricted cubic spline model to the data like so, which works great:

```
mod1 <- ols(value ~ rcs(time, 3) * location, data = dat, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
```

However, since repeated measures were taken from each fish over time, the model is autocorrelated. To deal with this, I am trying to add fish as a random variable to the model (if this is not the best way to deal with autocorrelation, please correct me). I found I can incorporate a random variable into a cubic spline model with the merlin package as so:

```
library(merlin)

mod2 <- mlrcs(formula = value ~ rcs(time, 3) + location, random  = ~ 1 | fish, data = dat)
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:22: unexpected symbol
1: value ~rcs(time, 3)  location
                         ^
```

The code works just fine when I remove "+ location" like so:

```
mod3 <- mlrcs(formula = value ~ rcs(time, 3), random  = ~ 1 | fish, data = dat)
```

I also don't appear to be able to include the interaction term:

```
mod4 <- mlrcs(formula = value ~ rcs(time, 3) * location, random  = ~ 1 | fish, data = dat)
```

As I get the following error message:

```
Error in rcs(gml, time, 3) * location : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any ideas about what these error messages mean and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at its source code, `mlrcs`'s primary job is to interpret the formula you provide and pass that to the `merlin::merlin` function. But to be parsed correctly, formulas given to `mlrcs` require that the intercept to be specified. Your formula does not include an intercept, and so you see the error message. This behavior should probably be added to '?mlrcs' help file.

Also, the 'location' variable should be numeric with zeros and ones. With these adjustments your code fits a model.

```
dat = as.data.frame(list(fish = as.factor(c(rep("a",6),rep("b",6),rep("c",6),rep("d",6))),
                         value = as.numeric(c(1,3,7,7,6,7,2,4,8,7,7,6,5,8,10,11,12,10,3,7,9,9,8,9)),
                         time = as.numeric(rep(1:6,4)),
                         location = c(rep(0,6),rep(1,6)))) # adjust

library(merlin)

# formula with intercept
mod2 <- mlrcs(formula = value ~  1 + rcs(time, 3) + location, random  = ~ 1 |fish, data = dat)

> summary(mod2)
Restricted cubic splines model
Log likelihood = -30.32352

Estimate Std. Error       z Pr(>|z|) [95% Conf.  Interval]
rcs():1         1.6839262  0.1331443  12.647   0.0000  1.4229681  1.9448843
rcs():2         1.2721426  0.1331443   9.555   0.0000  1.0111846  1.5331006
rcs():3         0.0005585  0.1331444   0.004   0.9967 -0.2603997  0.2615167
location       -3.7102135  0.3665079 -10.123   0.0000 -4.4285559 -2.9918711
_cons           9.2959865  0.2531929  36.715   0.0000  8.7997376  9.7922355
log_sd(resid.) -0.4272951  0.1440364  -2.967   0.0030 -0.7096012 -0.1449890
log_sd(M1)      0.5468268  0.0827878   6.605   0.0000  0.3845657  0.7090879
```